Migrate Data(including images) From Wix Programattically using Velo
I am working on migrating my data from wix. I am using Wix Velo. I have the below custom API using wix-http functions.
import { ok, notFound, serverError } from "wix-http-functions";
import wixData  from "wix-data";

export function get_shoesListing(request) {
    let options = {
        "headers": {
            "Content-Type": "application/json"
        }
    };
    let productsQuery = wixData.query("Stores/Products");

    return productsQuery
        .find()
        .then((results)=> {
            if (results.items.length > 0) {
                options.body = {
                    "items": results.items
                }
                return ok(options);
            }
            return notFound(options)
        })
        .catch((error)=> {
            options.body = {
                "error": error.message
            };
            return serverError(options);
        });
}

From the above I have a custom URL endpoint where i perform get request get all data with an exception of sites images download urls which I need to use wix media manager.
Showing media items

https://dev.wix.com/docs/velo/api-reference/wix-media-backend/media-manager/download-files
I can not figure out how to combine wix-http functions and wix media manager downloadFiles() functions to enable to enable me to download both the images and data programmatically.
PS; Wix http functions dose not expose image urls directly.
Please assist.

There are two basic approaches to get the external URLs for the images.

Velo wix-media APIs: As you suggested, you can use these APIs within your HTTP function to get a download URL for the images. To do so, you need to loop through all the items returned in you query and then loop through each items image files to gather all the internal Wix URLs. Then you can send those to the media function to create a download URL (there is a newer version of the function than the one you linked to). Note that this will work for up to 1000 images at a time.

SDK media APIs: You can also leave your HTTP function as it is, and deal with converting the internal URL to some code you run outside of the Wix environment. To do so, use the SDK's Media module APIs to convert internal Wix URLs to external URLs. Once you have those, you can download the files however you like.


